# Workbench error

Tags: error, workbench

When the use the following query:

```
SELECT Id,Name,Status_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c 
WHERE Status_vod__c = 'Submitted_vod' and LastModifiedDate<= 2017-03-31T23:59:00Z
```

I get the following error message.

> A fatal error occurred. Contact your administrator and provide the following error id:
>
> [future_get-9-1555616270]

Comment: I know that Workbench directs you here for questions, but note that this is a community site. What that error says is that something happened on [line 9 of future_get.php](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/master/workbench/future_get.php#L9) (which submits the query to Salesforce and renders the results asynchonously), at the time stamp that follows the second dash. Have you tried the query from Developer Console? How many results would you expect to be returned? Try adding a `LIMIT 10` at the end to see if the query completes or generates a more useful error.