# Workbench returning an error on a simple query

Tags: error, workbench

One of our users is attempting to run a query on the EmailMessage object in the Workbench tool but receives an error every time he attempts it. Myself and a few other people are able to run the query without issue, and we've confirmed that he has the necessary permissions to perform this action.

Here is the query in text form:

SELECT ActivityId FROM EmailMessage LIMIT 10

And here is the error message he receives:

A fatal error occurred. Contact your administrator and provide the following error id:
[future_get-9-1596644771]

Comment: Take a look at a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258376/workbench-error) for some troubleshooting advice

Comment: Can you please ask the affected user to try by running the same query in Developer console to see if it works or get any other specific error which might help us.